# Побитовые операции(код)

Tags: c++

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
 unsigned short z, c, v=0;
 int x;
 x= rand()%16;
 v=(z << x) || ();
 printf("x = %d\n",x);
 printf("V = %i\n",v);
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Помогите исправить код, нужно заполнить два 16-битовые числа z и c. После взять число x, случайную точку разрыва, от 0 до 16. И заполнить число v таким образом, чтобы до случайного числа было z, после - с.
Пример: случайное число 4 => v=zzzzcccccccccccc;

Comment: что из себя у вас представляет v?  16*16 бит? Это что вообще получится то?

Comment: 16-битовое число которое состоит из z до случайного числа, а после него - c.

Comment: вы прочитайте текст своего вопроса. сами z и c у вас по условию 16 битовые числа, не может другое 16 бит число их как-то включать по несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
unsigned short mask = 0xFFFF << (16-x);
v = (z&mask)|(c&~mask);
```

Если, конечно, имеется в виду, чтобы в `v` были *соответствующие* биты `z` и `c`.

```
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
||||
vvvv

zzzzcccccccccccc

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ||||||||||||
cccccccccccccccc
```

Comment: Спасибо, не могли б вы ещё подсказать как лучше инициализировать z=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.

Comment: Не понял? Это же число, которое вы сами вводите...